# Easy to use shared memory library in C

Tags: c, linux, open-source, shared-memory

I am new to writing applications that use shared memory. I am writing a C application and I want to use shared memory.

I know that it is very easy to shoot oneself in the foot when using shared memory, so ideally, I would like to use an established, peer reviewed (i.e. open source) light weight C library that makes writing apps that use shared memory easy, and takes care of any 'gotchas' automagically.

Can anyone recommend a lightweight ANSI shared memory library that a (shmem novice) can use to get up to speed in writing an application?

Note: I am only concerned about running on Linux platforms

Comment: Shared memory isn't part of ANSI C; you'd need to use POSIX.  Ignoring that detail, be aware that it is unlikely that libraries can take care of all the gotchas automagically.  You use shared memory between processes; you have to coordinate access to the shared memory to keep it coherent.  You'd have to use the library functions exclusively to access the shared memory, which eliminates some of the benefits of using shared memory.  I'm not sure it counts as lightweight, but you could look at the [Apache Portability Runtime (APR)](http://apr.apache.org/).

Comment: Your question is too vague to have a clear answer. Please describe the purpose of your code. Otherwise the only thing that we can tell you is that shared memory works well with Linux. Use `shm_open` and `mmap` to acquire shared segments (not the oldish `shmat` stuff). And then all the POSIX lock primitives in Linux support placement in process shared memory with some options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @akhil says `mmap` can be used, but if you are looking for an easy way to share memory (on Linux), the simplest way is to read-write on `/dev/shm` as it was a ramdisk, keep in mind that you can not always rely on `/dev/shm` being present.

RedHat and Debian based distributions include it by default since Linux kernel 2.6

More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory#Support_on_UNIX_platforms

Answer (score 0):

I think the mmap() can be used for sharing memory across process. Also in Android ashmem is used of sharing memory. I think  asmem is available with the latest Linux kernel.